# Disable option select javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I Have a problem, I want to enable/show options, if that option has the same name with "ColumnCode" and "IsRow" is  true. Other than that, the option is disabled/ hidden.

I tried the code below, but it didn't work.

```
var model = {
    Rows: $('#Rows')
};


var columns = 
[{"ColumnCode":"CollateralType","IsRow":true},
{"ColumnCode":"CollectorUnit","IsRow":true}];

_.each(columns, function (col) {
    model.Rows.find('option').each(function () {                       
        if (this.value != col['ColumnCode'] || (this.value == col['ColumnCode'] && !col['IsRow']))
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

This is the select element :

```
<select name="Rows[]" id="Rows">
    <option value="AccountNo">Account No</option>
    <option value="CollateralType">Collateral Type</option>  
</select>
```

Can someone please guide?

Comment: plain javascript only? is jQuery allowed?

Comment: jQuery allowed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn that loop inside out and iterate through the options first and then the array as otherwise your options will get constantly re-set or could end up all disabled all the time.

You also might want to add a default option similar to `<option value="none">...please select</option>` value to ensure nothing is getting selected in case all are disabled.

```
var model = {
    Rows: $('#Values') // had to change this from #Row for demo to work
};

var columns = [
    {"ColumnCode": "CollateralType", "IsRow": true},  // change this to see different results
    {"ColumnCode": "CollectorUnit",  "IsRow": true}
];

// enable option if option has the same name as "ColumnCode" and "IsRow" is true
model.Rows.find('option').each(function (index, option) {
    var matchFound = false;
    var isRow = false;

    _.each(columns, function (col) {
        if (option.value == col['ColumnCode']) {
            matchFound = true;
            isRow = col['IsRow']
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(matchFound && !isRow || !matchFound){
        $(this).attr('disabled', true); //jQuery pre 1.6
        //$(this).prop('disabled', true); // jQuery v1.6 or later
    }
});
```

If you have this happening dynamically and need to reset all disabled attributes, simply do `model.Rows.find('option').removeAttr('disabled')` or if you are using jQuery 1.6 or later use `model.Rows.find('option').prop('disabled', false)` before you start the loops.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mvk4g/) - Only enable options which are in the list and have isRow set to true

---

Comment: You should probably be using `$(this).prop('disabled', true)` and then `model.Rows.find('option').prop('disabled', false)`.

Comment: @idbehold: While I was merely focusing on getting the solution to work, your advise is absolutely correct when using jQuery 1.6 or later. Just as advised in the jQuery [**prop() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [**attr() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as `disabled` is a DOM property rather than an attribute. I edited the answer to include this information.